# How to expand code/description to a complex object?

Tags: java, mysql, rest, class, android-mvvm

I want to present a list of the names/basic attributes of some complex objects (i.e. they are comprised of multiple collections of other objects) in a recycler view, then get the full object on user selection. For example, the top level objects are "Play Scripts", and each contains a number of "Spoken Lines" spoken by one of the "Actors" associated with the Play Script.

I'm trying to use the Android Architecture components to do this and have (using Florian @ codinginflow.com 's tutorials) successfully used Room to create a simplified Play_Script class, DAO and Repository. I've also created some basic REST web services in ASP.Net which can serve up data from a MySQL db.

It strikes me that the path that I am going down will perform poorly and use excessive network bandwidth getting lots of data that I won't use. I'm getting every Play Script (including its Spoken Lines etc) just so that I have the Play Script "Name" and "Description" attributes to populate the Recycler.

In the olden days, I'd just "SELECT ID, Name, Description FROM Play_Script" and once the user had made their choice, I'd use the ID as the key to get everything else that I needed. I suspect that I'm missing something fundamental in the design of my data entities but can't come up with any keywords that would let me search for examples of this common sort of task being done well (/at all).

Please can you help this SO noob with his 1st question?

Cheers,
Z

**Update 15 May:**
Though I haven't had a response, from what I've been reading in recent weeks (e.g. re Dependency Injection) I suspect that there is no blanket approach for this sort of thing in Android development. It appears that people generally either retrieve extensive data and then use what they require or else build multiple Web Service APIs to return sparse data that includes keys that the client can use to expand when required. So, for example you might make both a "plays_light" and a "plays_detail" Get API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution has been exactly as my May update - i.e. to extend the web API and offer a number of similar calls that return varying granularities of information. It's not particularly elegant and I suspect there may be better ways but it works. In general, I'm finding that the user tends to need less detail in the parent entities and more as we get to individual children/grandchildren.

I do now realise why some apps are so slow though: It's easy to be lazy in the web service design and just return loads of data - only a fragment of which will be used by the client - and justify this by convincing yourself that single API will be universally applicable and thus easier for whoever picks up my code down the line to understand.

Again, it could be my inexperience but I find the local caching of relational data on the Android side retrieved through the API calls quite clunky - lots of storing foreign keys and then re-parsing json to get data into the SQLite tables. I'd hoped Dagger would have been more useful in simplifying this than it has turned out to be so far. I actually unravelled a whole load of Dagger-related code just to preserve my sanity. Not sure I was entirely successful!

Better answers are still very much welcome.
Z